# When submitting a form with a fields_for part, how can I assign the new id to the fields_for model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, fields-for

I have a form that handles 2 models, Vehiculo and Poliza. This is how I have them set up right now:

```
class Vehiculo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :poliza
end

class Poliza < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vehiculo
end
```

The create method on Vehiculo looks like this:

```
def create
    @vehiculo = Vehiculo.new(params[:vehiculo])
    @polizadeseguro = Polizadeseguro.new(params[:poliza])

respond_to do |format|
  if @vehiculo.save #&& @poliza.save

    format.html { redirect_to(@vehiculo, :notice => 'Vehiculo was successfully created.') }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @vehiculo, :status => :created, :location => @vehiculo }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @vehiculo.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end

end
```

The form on /vehiculos/new has a @fields_for part with the fields from poliza. When I submit the form, it is saving all the fields, but it is not assigning the just created id from vehiculo, to vehiculo_id on the Polizas table. After reading many questions about this online, It seems that it should save it "automagically" based on the relationships on the model. Is this true? If so, why isn't it working? If not, what do I need to add to the create method so I resolve this?

Thanks!

Update:
After updating the create method with json as output as suggested here is what I get:

```
{
  "utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"tEhNC4J17h+KvNgXv1LLkVyufQwU2uAT18P7msQxiqA=",
  "vehiculo"=>{
    "marca_id"=>"2",
    "modelo_id"=>"4",
    "color"=>"Blanco",
    "ano"=>"2011",
    "chassis"=>"123456789",
    "placa"=>"G123456",
    "cliente_id"=>"1",
    "entaller"=>"0",
    "vip"=>"0"
  },
  "poliza"=>{
    "compania"=>"Comp1",
    "numeropoliza"=>"736458",
    "vencimiento(1i)"=>"2011",
    "vencimiento(2i)"=>"9",
    "vencimiento(3i)"=>"21"
  }
}
```

That's the output, so at least it is getting the fields from the form, but it is not inserting them to the polizas table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that your parent model accepts nested attributes for the child model:

```
class Vehiculo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :poliza
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :poliza
end
```

Assuming your form is set up correctly, your `params` will look something like this:

```
params = {
  :vehiculo => {
    :field => "value",
    :another_field => "value",
    :poliza => {
      :poliza_field => "poliza value"
    }
  }
}
```

So all you should need in your controller is:

```
def create
  @vehiculo = Vehiculo.new(params[:vehiculo])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @vehiculo.save #&& @poliza.save
      format.html { redirect_to(@vehiculo, :notice => 'Vehiculo was successfully created.') }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @vehiculo, :status => :created, :location => @vehiculo }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @vehiculo.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

**[Update]**

Here's what you'll need to have to have this all work.

As mentioned above, you need `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

Next, make sure your new action is building the child.

```
class VehiculosController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @vehiculo = Vehiculo.new
    @vehiculo.build_poliza
  end

  def create
    vehiculo = Vehiculo.new(params[:vehiculo])
    if vehiculo.save
      redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Success"
    else
      redirect_to root_path, :alert => "Failure"
    end
  end
end
```

Finally, in your view, reference the child model using `fields_for :child_model`, as such:

```
<%= form_for @vehiculo do |f| %>
  <p>Whatever Field: <%= f.text_field :whatever %></p>
  <%= f.fields_for :poliza do |p| %>
    <p>Polizo Field: <%= p.text_field :something %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I just added the 'accepts_nested_attributes_for' and removed '&& @poliza.save' and now it is not even saving the other fields from poliza. I'm using '<%= fields_for @poliza do |p| %>' for the fields. I just checked the logs and the params look as you said, with the data from the fields from poliza, but it's only doing 'INSERT INTO Vehiculos' and no insert to Polizas. Any ideas why it is not saving?

Comment: That's a good question; I'm not positive off the top of my head. If you're willing to do a little detective work, that might help. Change your `create` method to have: `render :json => params and return` as the first line, and maybe update your question with that output, and we can go from there.

Comment: Actually I think there's something up with the `new` action and the view now that I think about it. I'm updating the question presently.

Comment: Now I'm getting this 'undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass' when I call /vehiculos/new. The problem is with the line I added to the new method the '@vehiculo.poliza.build'.

Comment: Gah! My deepest apologies, I forgot this is a `has_one` not a `has_many`. It should be `@vehiculo.build_poliza` instead. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Those params (in your `json` output) are not correct for nested attributes. It's likely your form is not being built right. We could take a look at that if you wanted to post it. :)

Comment: Dumb me, I didn't see the f. before fields_for. After I changed to f.fields_for and used the build_poliza instead of poliza.build everythings fine. Thanks a lot for all your help!